# Initial delay in animation while using Universal Tween Engine in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, tween

I am using the universal tween library in LibGdx to move the Sprite from top to Middle of the screen as mentioned in the below code. I could see there is  remarkable delay before the animation starts. I even set the delay as 0f still I am not able to resolve it. Please assist.

```
    sprite1 = new Sprite(LEVEL_SELECTION_BOARD);  

    // Top to bottom 

    sprite1.setPosition((SCREEN_WIDTH/2) - LEVEL_SELECTION_BOARD .getWidth()/2 ,SCREEN_HEIGHT); 

    Tween.to(sprite1,SpriteTween.POSITION_Y,20f)
    .delay(0f)
    .target( SCREEN_HEIGHT /2 - LEVEL_SELECTION_BOARD.getHeight()/2)  
    .ease(TweenEquations.easeOutBack) 
    .setCallback(callbackEnd) 
    .setCallbackTriggers(TweenCallback.END)
    .start(tweenManagerLevelBoard);   


@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {  
    //System.out.println("StartScreen - Render ");   
    batch=sb;
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sb.begin();   
    sb.draw(BACKGROUND,0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);     
    delta = (TimeUtils.millis()-startTime)/1000; // **get time delta **// 
    tweenManagerLevelBoard.update(delta); //** update sprite1 **//
    sprite1.draw(batch);
    sb.end(); 
}
```

Comment: Probably has to do with how you're initializing `startTime` (not shown).

Comment: I made it like this delta = (TimeUtils.millis()-startTime + 500)/1000  ;  Now it is fine

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
tweenManagerLevelBoard.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
```

Comment: if so the animation becomes very very slow. I still OK with the delta = (TimeUtils.millis()-startTime + 500)/1000